# Igualar variable JavaScript a php sin recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, variables

Me gustaría igualar una variable de javascript a php. He estando investigando mucho, pero me es imposible. He visto que se puede hacer mediante el método get y post.El problema que tengo es que al hacerlo con esos métodos se reinicia la página o te redirige a otra, y a mí me gustaría poder pasar la variable sin recargar la página. Muchas gracias.
PD: Así es como lo tenía realizado:

```
function idgrupo() {
 window.location.href = window.location.href + "?idgrupo=" + IDbutton;
}
idgrupo();
```

Y luego lo obtengo en el php así:

```
if (isset($_GET["idgrupo"])) {
$idgrupo = $_GET["idgrupo"];
echo "<p>Parameters: " . $idgrupo . "</p>";
} else {
 echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
}
```

Comment: Sin código solo podemos hacer conjeturas, puede ser que al recibir la respuesta tengas un reload o algo que te provoque el refresco, porque con un get podrias obtener el valor sin que realice un refresco

Comment: @Nicolas Oñate Ya he subido el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> después de mucha búsqueda, encontré y apliqué con excelentes resultados lo siguiente:

> llamar la librería para jquery ya que emplearemos ajax para el envío de la información

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> despues, desde una función pasamos los valores a una estructura ajax, la cual envirará la información en formato json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enviar(b){
var send = b;
  
$.ajax({
    url: 'descargas.php',
    type: 'post',
    datatype:'json',
    data:{
    carta:send}}).done(function(data){
    $('#salida').append(data);
    send;});}
</script>
```

> en el archivo php recibimos y pasamos el valor de json a una variable php

```
<?php 
    $clave = $_POST['carta'];
    $carta = $clave;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con preventDefault

Como no pusiste codigo te pondre un ejemplo

HTML

```
<form id="Ejemplo">
    <input type="number" name="Num" id="Num">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar!">
</form>
```

JS (usando jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Ejemplo').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Num: $('#Num').val() },
            url: 'Procesos/Ejemplo.php',
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

PHP, solo recibe e imprime el numero

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['Num'];

echo $num;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, sin embargo intenta evitar dar respuesta a preguntas mal formuladas. Sin un [mcve] es difícil saber lo que está intentando hacer el OP. Si bien tu ejemplo podría ilustrar una forma de hacerlo, haces muchas suposiciones, empezando por el hecho de que no sabes si el OP utiliza JQuery. Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras Lo siento mucho. Soy bastante nuevo y se me a olvidado poner el codigo. Ya he editado y le he colocado.